# Why are there two sets of Build and Rebuild options in my ASP.NET project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, telerik, asp.net-3.5, rebuild

It seems as if the success of building my ASP.NET (targeting .NET 3.5) project at least sometimes depends on whether I build it as a project or as a website.

I have these [re]build options beneath the Build menu:

```
Rebuild Project
Build Project
Rebuild Website
Build Website
```

Why does the project have dual personalities? What are the advantages/disadvantages or dos/dont's of building either the Project or the Website?

This makes me nervous, because I recently upgraded the Telerik components, and expected some compilation problems to result from that, but had no problems that way. I'm afraid that if I build this "the right way" compilation errors will indeed crop up.

### UPDATE

Is the selection of "Build Web site as part of solution" in the project's Build options:

[image]

...the reason why there is a pair of [Re]build Website options on the Build menu?

If so, what are the ramifications of deselecting that option? Why should I/should I not select it? Under what circumstances/scenarios is checking/unchecking preferred?

Should the project build option (right-click project, select "Start Options...", then "Build" from the list at left) "Before running startup page" be something other than what is currently selected ("Build Web Site")?

The other options are "No Build" and "Build Page"

Comment: Your question is evolving fast. Do not feed it after midnight. Do not put water on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. A Project

Projects are used in a solution to logically manage, build, and debug the items that make up your application. The output of a project is usually an executable program (.exe), a dynamic-link library (.dll) file or a module, among others.

Your project can contain Sites and some librairies that are common to your Site.

#### 2. Clean, Build and Rebuild

- Clean : Delete all compiled files from the bin/obj directory.
- Build : Compile any assemblies which have changes.
- ReBuild : Basically Clean + Build.(See Difference below)

Rebuild will clean and build Project after project.
Clean + Build , Will clean All Project frist. Then REbuild them from scratch.

Rebuild can even rebuild some project in paralele.

In some Strange case Clean + build give better result.

There is no reason to be afraid when you have no compilation error.
Dev Selfestem decrease when they gain experience till they are good enought to think they understand what they are doing.

#### Edit: For the Update question.

#### - Start Options

It's pretty clear.. When you press F5 Do you want Visual studio to :
a/. Do nothing   b/. Compile the current page if there is one open.  c/.The WebSite
There is no best choice, it depend on your use for simple project you can use the web site option. for bigger project with a lot of Work in progress page that wont compile use page or no page.

#### - Build Solution Action

Its basicaly Do you want the web site to be generate when you generate the solution or not ?
the question about what is the best to use has no generic answers.

I personnaly use both generate the site web and  as a part of solution in my current project

Ps: Do not edit your post with other  question create a new one.

Comment: I still wonder why I have both Project and Website; this project does not produce an .exe or a .DLL; why do I even have [Re]Build Project options?

Comment: I took the Msdn definition of project. But project is a logical box he can contain anything even serval web site.

Comment: Okay, but still: why are both needed? Isn't one enough? Should I build with both, or prefer one over the other, leaving the other one alone?

Comment: They are needed cause with big poject sometimes you want to rebuild only one small thing and not your 30+ web site and 10 years lib

Comment: Which one (Project or Website) would need to be [re]built for "one small thing"? My solution has one project, which is a website, that's all.

Comment: In your case they are the same.

Comment: So why are there two? And which one should I use, since they sometimes have different results?